# how to create non duplicated random numbers - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, random

I am creating a random number game that has 9 different numbers and i want to randomise the numbers so they are randomised with non duplicates (e.g., 1,4,2,3,6,5,9,7,8) but at the moment i am just getting 9random numbers between 1 and 9 with multiple duplicates. Can anyone suggest anything without changing the existing code too much.

Thank you.

```
-(IBAction)Randomise

{


int rNumber1 = arc4random_uniform(9);

Text1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber1 + 1];

if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
  [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
  [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
  [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}





int rNumber2 = arc4random_uniform(9);


Text2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber2+1];


if ([Text2.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text2.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text2.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text2.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text2.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text2.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
    [AnimatedPicture1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}


else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
  [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
  [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text1.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
  [AnimatedPicture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}




int rNumber3 = arc4random_uniform(9);


Text3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber3+1];


if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}

else if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text3.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
[AnimatedPicture2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}



int rNumber4 = arc4random_uniform(9);


Text4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber4+1];


if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}

else if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text4.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
[AnimatedPicture3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}



int rNumber5 = arc4random_uniform(9);


Text5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber5+1];


if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}

else if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text5.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
[AnimatedPicture4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}




int rNumber6 = arc4random_uniform(9);


Text6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber6+1];


if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}

else if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text6.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
[AnimatedPicture5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}



int rNumber7 = arc4random_uniform(9);


Text7.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber7+1];


if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}

else if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text7.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
[AnimatedPicture6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}




int rNumber8 = arc4random_uniform(9);


Text8.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber8+1];


if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}

else if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text8.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
[AnimatedPicture7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}



int rNumber9 = arc4random_uniform(9);


Text9.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",rNumber9+1];


if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
}

else if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"2"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
}

else if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"3"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
}

else if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"4"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];
}

else if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"5"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];
}

else if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"6"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];
}

else if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"7"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];
}

else if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"8"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];
}

else if ([Text9.text isEqualToString: @"9"])
{
[AnimatedPicture8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
}



AnimatedPicture.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];

AnimatedPicture1.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];

AnimatedPicture2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];

AnimatedPicture3.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];

AnimatedPicture4.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];

AnimatedPicture5.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];

AnimatedPicture6.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];

AnimatedPicture7.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];

AnimatedPicture8.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], nil];



[AnimatedPicture setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
 AnimatedPicture.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture startAnimating];


[AnimatedPicture1 setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
 AnimatedPicture1.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture1 startAnimating];

[AnimatedPicture2 setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
AnimatedPicture2.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture2 startAnimating];

[AnimatedPicture3 setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
AnimatedPicture3.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture3 startAnimating];

[AnimatedPicture4 setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
AnimatedPicture4.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture4 startAnimating];

[AnimatedPicture5 setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
AnimatedPicture5.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture5 startAnimating];

[AnimatedPicture6 setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
AnimatedPicture6.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture6 startAnimating];

[AnimatedPicture7 setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
AnimatedPicture7.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture7 startAnimating];

[AnimatedPicture8 setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
AnimatedPicture8.animationDuration = 1.0;
[AnimatedPicture8 startAnimating];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of the numbers you need and then randomly choose two numbers and switch their array positions. Do that random switch a hundred times or so. The idea is basically like shuffling a deck of cards.

Comment: Beat me to it, this is exactly what I was going to say. This should be quite efficient and easy to code.

Comment: I realise the array is the best way, but I was hoping that someone would show me the code for the array along with the code that I provided.